# Converting ArcGIS layer style to Styled Layer Descriptor (SLD) file?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, geoserver, sld

I am putting together a GIS server using GeoServer and need some help with importing my layer styles from ArcGIS 10 to [SLD](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/sld) format.

I have one layer in ArcMap properly symbolized and labeled, how can I get this layers symbolization and labeling into a SLD file?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Arc2Earth

The **Community Edition** can only export single layers, you'll need to upgrade to Pro if you want create a single SLD file for your entire Map. After your selection, click on the Export button and you will be asked for a location to export to.

[image]

http://help.arc2earth.com/help/faqs/arc2earth-desktop/export-map-symbols-to-styled-layer-descriptor-sld

Comment: I have it installed and the MXD I am using has 1 layer on it, whenever I try the Export Single Layer option the drop down menu is blank, any ideas?

Comment: EDIT: Never mind, I just got it to work!

Comment: Seems like Community Edition was killed and there is only paid version.

Comment: Now renamed Arc2Earth Lite http://www.arc2earth.com/software/arc2earth-lite/

Comment: Current Arc2Earth Lite users will have until June 1st, 2014 to upgrade to a full subscription. So no fun anymore.

Comment: Arc2Earth is closed for business, so this answer no longer helps.

Answer (score 8):

I was looking for the same thing just the other day and found this http://wald.intevation.org/projects/arcmap2sld/. I haven't tried it yet though so will be interested to hear if you do.

As noted by @AlexTereshenkov in a comment there is also a version for ArcGIS Desktop 10 - see bottom of the [A tool for reading out styling information from ArcMap® and converting into Styled Layer Descriptor-Files (SLD) of OGC page](http://arcmap2sld.i3mainz.hs-mainz.de/ArcMap2SLDConverter_Eng.htm).

Comment: Found this works for ArcGIS 9.3 but not ArcGIS 10. Furlong was looking for ArcGIS 10 solution. But yes a valid project that needs an update.

Comment: Does arcmap2sld work for ArcGIS 10?

Comment: It does, they released the ArcGIS 10 version: http://arcmap2sld.geoinform.fh-mainz.de/ArcMap2SLDConverter_Eng.htm

Comment: Unfortunately, the ArcMap2SLD Converter only works in ArcGIS 10.0, not in later versions such as 10.2

Also, Arc2Earth has deprecated their "lite" version.

Comment: ArcMap2SLD now supports ArcMap up to 10.5. More details here: http://arcmap2sld.i3mainz.hs-mainz.de/Dateianlagen/readme_english.txt . It can be downloaded from http://wald.intevation.org/frs/?group_id=32

Comment: Tested in 10.7 - seems to work fine

Answer (score 6):

I have confirmed that `arcmap2sld` tool is working fine on ArcGIS Desktop 10.1+. The program can be downloaded from this [link](http://wald.intevation.org/frs/?group_id=32&release_id=892#arcmap2sld-_1.4.0-title-content) and the [readme docs are here](https://arcmap2sld.i3mainz.hs-mainz.de/ArcMap2SLDConverter_Eng.htm).

> The program transforms an ArcMap project's layers symbology into an
>   `.sld` document which can be used in open-source software. It is
>   implemented in Visual Basic .NET and requires .NET 2.0.

The steps:

1. Unpack the `.zip` file.
2. Run the `"\stp\Adjust_for_ArcGIS-version.bat"` file which creates the configuration file `ArcGIS_SLD_Converter.exe.config` in the current folder. This configuration contains the metadata on ArcGIS system libraries available in your installation.
3. Run the `ArcGIS_SLD_Converter.exe` to start the program.

To be able to create `.sld` files, you need to have ArcMap application started with some layers added. So you add your feature classes to ArcMap, set the symbology needed and then use the `ArcGIS_SLD_Converter` to export each of the layers' symbology into a `.sld` file on disk. You can specify whether you want to export all layers into a single `.sld` file or into individual files (`Extras` menu > `Layers`).

There are certain limitations with regards to what type of symbology could be exported. Having a picture symbol will throw an error when trying to convert; some other symbols such as dashed line, will be downgraded into solid lines. You might want to experiment to see what symbology is supported.

Answer (score 4):

The best solution I've seen for arcgis to sld conversion is [GeoCat Bridge](http://www.geocat.net/bridge).  It's not free, but then again neither is ArcGIS 10.  It'll publish directly to your GeoServer, using its REST config API (and also stick your metadata on GeoNetwork).

Answer (score 0):

There is [SLD Converter for ArcGIS](http://www.mangosystem.com:8080/gxt/docs/gxt_for_desktop/sld_coverter_for_arcgis/index.html) for 10.0. I've not tested it as I cannot read the Korean text so have no means to vet for authenticity etc. Perhaps someone here can do that.

Found by way of comments to [Converting an ArcMap layer file into an SLD document](https://pvanb.wordpress.com/2012/11/09/converting-an-arcmap-project-file-into-an-sld-document/comment-page-1/) (2012).