# Is there a free and open-source MXD to SLD converter?

Tags: open-source-gis, mxd, sld

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to edit or convert ArcGIS 10 layer style to a SLD’s file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3755/how-to-edit-or-convert-arcgis-10-layer-style-to-a-slds-file)

I'm trying to set up a web map server for one of the government agencies in my country. Server setup's done (GeoServer) and now I'm just trying to integrate it to their current workflows. Unfortunately, they are currently using ArcGIS 9.3 and they're used to making maps using it and saving them as MXDs. I know they could style their maps again using SLD but they find it a bit troublesome and I don't want to give them another reason to resist FOSS. (They're resistant enough as it is)

Google searches return [GeoCat](http://geocat.net/bridge) but it's a paid product and I was hoping to test a free one first if possible. I also found [ArcMap2SLD](http://wald.intevation.org/frs/?group_id=32&release_id=213) but it crashes my computer and it hasn't been updated in some time. Anybody know some other tool?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See this GIS Stack Exchange link:

[Converting ArcGIS layer style to Styled Layer Descriptor (SLD) file?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3755/how-to-edit-or-convert-arcgis-10-layer-style-to-a-slds-file)

Comment: Thanks. Missed it while I was looking for similar questions. Was thinking in terms of MXDs and SLDs.