# ArcGIS layer format

Tags: ogc

Am I correct in saying that the ArcGIS layer format for styling maps (*.lyr) is not an OGC approved format? And this is the reason that QGIS cannot read the *.lyr files?

Comment: You are not correct in thinking that QGIS only supports OGC styling formats.

Answer (score 5):

The .lyr format is a closed ESRI only format.  It has not been reversed engineered.  If it was, we could add support in theory but I suspect it would be an expensive task.

Comment: There is a partial workaround of converting `.lyr` to `.sld` but it requires ArcGIS present to do the conversion: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24300/adding-layerfiles-lyr-to-qgis