# Can I export the RGB values from an ArcGIS layer symbology?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, symbology, color, rgb

I've got a point layer in ArcGIS that has 100 specific color codes based on the name of the store. I'm trying to export the RGB values for these colors (along with the name value it's tied to) so I can create a qml style file for QGIS.

So, basically I'm trying to apply ArcGIS symobology rules into a QGIS qgs project.

Anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Maybe. Symbology is typically stored in a lyr file for ArcGIS. As [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74781/arcgis-layer-format) notes, lyr file format is Esri proprietary and it's not 'readable' like a text or xml file. But the question of opening a lyr file in QGIS has been [asked before](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24300/adding-layerfiles-lyr-to-qgis) and the answer there suggests an intermediate step of lyr -> sld and then applying the sld in QGIS to create a qml. But I'm not aware of anyway to export an RGB value list short of manual lookup and type.

Comment: Were the colors applied via a ramp? If so, you might be able to convert the points to a raster and then export a color map (clr) file for said raster, which would have the RGB values in text format along with whatever attribute value goes with them. Roundabout way, but might be worth exploring.

Comment: Chris, thanks for the reply. No, colors are random. Just seems like arcpy / python should be able to loop through a layer in the map and tell me the RGB codes for the symbology. I don't need a lyr or sld file, i just want the RGB codes for the colors it's using.

Answer (score 1):

I found this [GEO thread Link](http://www.geothread.net/extract-legend-rgb-arcgis-javascript/)  which uses the java script API on server to extract from the JSON file.  Might be worth further investigation.