# Any clue how to read a .style (ArcGIS) file in Python, for converting into another platform-specific format?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, python, style

The problem I am face with is that I have all my data as shapefiles but my organization works with only 1 ArcGIS license. Migrating to QGIS to prominent amount of work, I need to convert my ArcGIS .style file to the .sld format of QGIS, to ensure uniformity of data capture and maps.

I am working with Python for this, Could anyone give me any suggestions?

Comment: There is also this question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24300/adding-layerfiles-lyr-to-qgis

Answer (score 3):

As stated in this Esri's [blog post](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2007/10/30/tips-for-managing-style-files/):

> The style files that are installed with ArcMap are actually Microsoft
>   Access databases, the file extension was changed from .mdb to .style.

The [blog post](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2007/10/30/tips-for-managing-style-files/) also describes a few useful things you can do to edit style files using Microsoft Access.

Please refer to this SO answer on [How to deal with mdb access files with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620539/how-to-deal-with-mdb-access-files-with-python).

Answer (score 0):

Reading style in Python and export it to SLD format sounds like pretty extensive piece of work. There is already solution for that as part of Arc2Earth - more info here:

[Converting ArcGIS layer style to Styled Layer Descriptor (SLD) file?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3755/how-to-edit-or-convert-arcgis-10-layer-style-to-a-slds-file)

There are also answers with few other solutions. If you really want to program it, I would consider to program it as plugin for QGIS - I am sure there are a lot of people who would like to have this feature in QGIS - including myself.