# Opening *.lyr file in QGIS without access to ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: qgis, layer-file

Is there a way to open a *.lyr file in QGIS without using ArcGIS for Desktop?

I have no access to ArcGIS, so the solution explained in [Adding Layerfiles (.lyr) to QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24300/adding-layerfiles-lyr-to-qgis) is not an option.

I have a *.lyr file with a lot of information and it is not possible to reproduce it all by myself.

Comment: There is a suggested solution there that does not require ArcGIS - Arc2SLD. The link was broken, but I have updated it. Also note http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3755/ which offers other non-free solutions. Links there might be broken, haven't checked.