# Exporting Symbology from ArcGIS for Desktop to Microstation or QGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, symbology, export, microstation

I am using ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop and trying to figure out how to export my symbols of elements in ArcGIS to CAD or QGIS readable format.

The problem is, that I can export symbology to a Style, or export a map to DGN, but there will be an export of just graphics without symbology.

Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Have you checked into any legal copyrights that may go along with the stock ArcGIS symbols? I'm not sure if they have any, but it seems like most software has legal usage languange built into it.  It may be worth checking out before you got to the effort of finding a way to convert them.

Answer (score 2):

I've used all the softwares mentioned above and have never been able to synchronize the symbology between the three. It appears your best bet is to go from ArcGIS to SLD (which QGIS will read). It appears the best answer currently is Arc2Earth (http://www.arc2earth.com/products/download/). I've never tried it- but I've found several references to this [Converting ArcGIS layer style to Styled Layer Descriptor (SLD) file?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3755/how-to-edit-or-convert-arcgis-10-layer-style-to-a-slds-file) .