# Creating an ArcGIS Add-In to Export SLD

Tags: arcgis-desktop, add-in, sld

If I wanted to create an add-in for ArcGIS that exported the styling of a layer to SLD how much work would it be and what languages could I use?

More info:

I'm an experienced programmer, and have done a lot of coding for GIS systems but am not a user of ESRI products and have never tried writing an extension for any of their products.

I would only need to export basic styling to SLD, not write a comprehensive tool that works for everything.

Comment: Hi ChrisInCambo May be following link will be helpful for you   http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3755/how-to-edit-or-convert-arcgis-10-layer-style-to-a-slds-file

Comment: I've seen that tool, but I actually want to build something myself.

Answer (score 1):

There is one project - ArcGIS-map to SLD Converter - with the [open source](http://wald.intevation.org/frs/?group_id=32&release_id=496#arcmap2sld-arcmap2sld-converter-1.3.0-code--title-content) available. It's been written in VB.NET and .NET, so you should be able to reuse this piece of code in an [ArcGIS Add-in based on .NET](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Building_add_ins_for_ArcGIS_for_Desktop/0001000000w2000000/).

If you are not familiar with ArcObjects, it would quite a big investment in time. Another approach would be to investigate the [SLD specification](https://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=1188) and then write an add-in in Python (new in 10.1) where you don't have to deal with ArcObjects (or maybe [just call some parts of ArcObjects in Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80/how-do-i-access-arcobjects-from-python)).