# How to convert ArcMap color ramps to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, color

I have both ArcGIS 10.0 and QGIS 2.0

How can I reproduce a specific ArcGIS color ramp in QGIS?

If possible, I would like to simply convert the Esri *.style file but perhaps there is another approach that I am not aware of.

I would prefer not to have to manually create a new QGIS color ramp from scratch.

Comment: Your Question contains two questions which does not align well with the Q&A format of GIS SE.  Would you be able to use the edit button to revise your Question so that it focuses on the single question of more importance to you, and then research/ask the other one separately, please?

Comment: Well, I removed the second topic.  When will my question be posted to the Stack Exchange world?

Comment: It has been posted on GIS SE since yesterday.  Our Comments are made to try and help it attract the attention of potential Answerers.

Comment: Technically, an ArcGIS _*.style_ file is a Jet v4 database (= MS Access database), and can be opened with any tool that can view _*.mdb_ files, like [mdb-tools](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mdbtools/) for Linux, or via [_pyodbc_ within Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620539/how-to-deal-with-mdb-access-files-with-python). The table "Color Ramps" has 5 fields and contains the color information in binary form. I try to dig deeper here, but this may take some time. If we know more details, it should be possible to generate a _QGIS xml_ or use [cptutils](http://bit.ly/1b9GDYB).

Answer (score 1):

You could use one of the tools in [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3755/how-to-edit-or-convert-arcgis-10-layer-style-to-a-slds-file) to convert your ArcMap style to SLD. And them load the sld style in QGIS. I haven't tested this, just an idea.