# Importing ArcGIS Pro Map styles to QGIS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-pro, style

I will have to switch from ArcGIS Pro to QGIS because my uni license runs out soon.

How can I import my map styles from ArcGIS Pro to a QGIS project?

I only know how to do it in ArcMap which I cannot use anymore.

Comment: SLYR (Community Edition) https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/slyr_community/ note: there is a paid for version that opens up more functionality  see future work https://north-road.com/slyr/#future_work

Comment: From what I know, there is nothing there besides SLYR, and for the moment, its not usable with PRO.

Answer (score 3):

The process involves converting ArcGIS .lyr styles or QGIS qml styles, which essentially involves converting the styles to what is called an SLD (Style Layer Descriptor).
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Styled_Layer_Descriptor

Here is a video tutorial showing how this person does it.
https://www.burdgis.com/blog/view/convert-arcgis-layer-files-lyr-to-qgis-styles-qml/

There are also plugins available from within ArcMap called Arc2Earth which was the accepted answer in this thread.
[Converting ArcGIS layer style to Styled Layer Descriptor (SLD) file?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3755/converting-arcgis-layer-style-to-styled-layer-descriptor-sld-file)

Honestly though those tools can be more trouble than what they are worth - a lot depends on how you have styled your map! Unless you have hundreds of layer files, my opinion and experience is to just manually recreate them in QGIS.